How is sree-raga described in Sangita ratnakara?
There is an ancient Indian musicological text called Sangita ratnakara which mentions the characteristics of sree-rāga in the verse which is given below. My question is what is the arohana and avarohana of
sree-rāga according to this verse?
षड्जे षाड्जीममुद्भूतं श्रीरागं स्वल्पपञ्चमम् । सन्यामांशग्रहं मन्द्रगान्धारं तारमध्यमम् ॥१५९॥ समशेषस्वरं वीरे शास्ति श्रीकरणाग्रणीः ।

Can you add a translation of the verse?  Machine translation returned something that I can't make much sense of; I assume that someone who knows Indian music theory can do somewhat better.
